# Map JSON values into another JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json

Background to this question is I have JSON Responses A and wish to send Response A's values only to JSON format B. JSON format B has different fields.

**JSON Response A**

{

```
"res_comment": "work description",
"res_id": "62",
"res_priority": "P2",
"res_qid": "INC0140315"
```

}
....... etc x n

Looking to map the values in JSON Response A to the below JSON format B.

**JSON format B**

{

```
"ServiceIssueCategoryID": "62", **#res_id**
 "ServicePriorityCode": "P2", **#res_priority**
"ServiceNowID_KUT": "INC0140315", **#res_qid**
"ServiceRequestTextCollection":[
{
    "TypeCode": "10004", **value does not change**
    "Text": "work description" **#res_comment**
}
    ]
```

}

## update

To be clear:

I have made a single map of Values (between one set of curly brackets) to Format B. Then I used the below to update Format B:

```
with open("sapFormat.json", "r+") as jsonFile: 
    data = json.load(jsonFile) 
    tmp1 = data['ServiceIssueCategoryID'] 
    data["ServiceIssueCategoryID"] = res_id

    .... other fields
```

Works fine, however I have 100's of these individual 'res_id'. Not sure how to loop through all individually and add individually. The function that pulls the Values, takes all Values, e.g. 100 x res_id, need to take 1 res_id, update B and move to the next res_id, update etc

Comment: what have you tried and why did not it work?

Comment: Hi, I have made a single map of Values (between one set of curly brackets) to Format B. Then I used the below to update Format B

with open("sapFormat.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
     data = json.load(jsonFile)
     tmp1 = data['ServiceIssueCategoryID']
     data["ServiceIssueCategoryID"] = res_id

Works fine,however I have 100's of these individual 'res_id'. Not sure how to loop through all individually and add individually. The function that pulls the Values, takes all Values, e.g. 100 x res_id, need to take 1 res_id, update B and move to the next res_id, update etc

Comment: could you please update the question with your explanation. it's quite hard to read the pieces of code in the comments, and unfortunately there's no way to format the code in the comments =(